# How to configure Keepalived to act as L4 load balancer via direct routing method

Tags: iptables, haproxy, nat, keepalived

Trying to achieve L4 load balancing via Keepalived in front of HAProxy that will act as L7 load balancer. Both Keepalived and HAProxy are on separate machines. I managed to get everything in the below image working but when I try to send a request to the public virtual IP (i.e. 115.101.1.17), **the connection always times out**.

As per my understanding from the documentation that states:

> In order for the real servers to directly respond to the public users’ requests, each real server must use the VIP as its source address when sending replies.

I tried to reset the source IP using SNAT on the HAProxy machine but still the same thing happens.

**Rules used for iptables on real servers (HAProxy machines)**

```
iptables \
  -A POSTROUTING \
  -t nat \
  -p tcp \
  --dport 80 \
  -j SNAT \
  --to-source 115.101.1.17
```

**keepalived.conf**

```
vrrp_instance VI_1 {
  state       MASTER     # [1]
  interface   eth0       # [2]
  advert_int  1          # [3]
  priority    100        # [4]

  virtual_router_id  92  # [5]

  # Authentication for VRRP messages
  authentication {
    auth_type  PASS
    auth_pass  pass123
  }

  virtual_ipaddress {
    115.101.1.17 dev eth0  # [6]
  }
}

virtual_server 115.101.1.17 80 {
  lb_algo   rr             # [1]
  lb_kind   DR             # [2]
  protocol  TCP

  delay_loop           10  # [3]
  persistence_timeout  60  # [4]

  # Backend Server (HAProxy LB-01)
  real_server 10.0.1.2 80 {
    weight 100

    TCP_CHECK {
      connect_timeout 5
      nb_get_retry 3
      delay_before_retry 2
    }
  }

  # Backend Server (HAProxy LB-02)
  real_server 10.0.1.3 80 {
    weight 100

    TCP_CHECK {
      connect_timeout 5
      nb_get_retry 3
      delay_before_retry 2
    }
  }
}
```

**sysctl.conf**

```
net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Any help will be appreciated.

[image: image of keepalived and haprxoy setup]

Answer (score 0):

You are using DR mode , so when the packet arrives at the HAProxy server it will say hi I'm looking for the VIP 115.101.1.17... and HAProxy must respond yes that's me.
So it must be bound to that address.
and the Linux box it is running on must also be configured to accept traffic to that address.
And therefore you will need to solve the arp problem. Try googling Dr mode arp problem Linux.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/oracle-linux/6/admin/section_vmd_ys2_4r.html

Or change the lbkind to NAT mode and just use the keep alive node as your default gateway. Which should be easy as you have two subnets already.

But personally I still agree with Andrews blog about DR mode: https://www.loadbalancer.org/blog/15-years-later-we-still-love-dsr/